# How to do the color for a particular row in a gridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I am using two forms,when I am sending the StockID from one form to another form,in the second form there is some data in the gridview,now I wan to do tat is,by using that id I want to highlight the that row only. I want to compare the ID is exists in the gridview or not,if exits the I want to Do the higlighten for that full row.,

```
if (pc == c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grid_stock.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        grid_stock.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.grid_stock.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        break;
    }                       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// on load or when refersh data

if (SelectingID != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgvInvoiceList.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        BillingGeneral.InvoicesDataSet.InvoiceListRow dr = (BillingGeneral.InvoicesDataSet.InvoiceListRow)((DataRowView)dgvInvoiceList.Rows[i].DataBoundItem).Row;
        if (dr.ID == SelectingID.Value)
        {
            dgvInvoiceList.ClearSelection();
            dgvInvoiceList.Rows[i].Selected = true;
            SelectingID = null;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Give correct column index of `StockID` in `row.Cells[0]`

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid_stock.Rows) 
{
  if (row.Cells[0].Value.Equals("StockID")) 
  {
    grid_stock.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the if condition at the top is meant to check if the IDs match , put that inside of your for loop , like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid_stock.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if(grid_stock.Rows[i].Cells[stockID_column_index].Value == received_stockID) // Check if the row IDs match here
    {
        grid_stock.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.grid_stock.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        break;
    }
}
```

Replace stockID_column_index with the index of the column where StockID is stored .